# Getting the value of a checked radio PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, get, radio-button

The following code is the code i am using:

```
<form action="sendinfo.php" method="post" id="form">
                -Title:<br>
                <input type="text" class="u-full-width" name="title" placeholder="Insert a title" >
                <br>-Date<br>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="date" placeholder="Click to add a date"><hr>
                <br>-Buildyear:<br>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="buildyear" placeholder="click to add buildyear">

                <br>-rebuild<br>
                <input id="1" type="radio" name="rebuildyes" value="yes"><label for="1">tes</label>
                <input id="2" type="radio" name="rebuildno" value="No"><label for="2">No</label><hr>

                <input type="submit" value="send" class="u-full-width">
</form>
```

The other code is :

```
 <?php
        //variables
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $buildyear = $_POST['buildyear']; 
            $rebuildyes = $_POST['rebuildyes'];
            $rebuildno = $_POST['rebuildno'];

        //in browser 
            echo "<h1>The inserted data has been locally stored as " . $title . " " . $date . ".txt</h1>";
            echo "<p>click <a href='index.html'>Here</a> to return to the previous screen</p>";



        //write text file.
            $file = fopen($title . " " . $date . ".txt","w");
            if ($date) fwrite($file, "Date: " . $date . "\r\n");
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
            if ($buildyear) fwrite($file, "Buildyear: " . $buildyear . "\r\n");
            if ($rebuildyes) fwrite($file, "Rebuild? " . $rebuildyes . "\r\n");
            if ($rebuildno) fwrite($file, "Rebuild? " . $rebuildno . "\r\n");

    ?>
```

Result of this code is a generated text file with the data filled in in the form given on the first page. The problem here is that i can't get the radio buttons to work, atleast i can't get the data out of them. When they are empty they should not be written down in the file, when they are selected they should be.

Also, please dont tell me this is a dangerous way of coding PHP since i know it gives users acces to write where ever the PHP has acces to, but this "project" will only be accesable for a small amount of people and won't actually be hosted server wise. That being said if you have a better way for me building this project, not risk wise, just PHP wise, please tell me since i'm just starting coding PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your radio buttons a group :

```
<input id="1" type="radio" name="rebuild" value="yes"><label for="1">tes</label>
<input id="2" type="radio" name="rebuild" value="no"><label for="2">No</label><hr>
```

Then, check if the user selected the 'yes' value :

```
if (isset($_POST['rebuild']) && $_POST['rebuild'] == 'yes') {
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: Did the following :                    if (isset($_POST['rebuild']) && $_POST['rebuild'] == 'yes') {
                    fwrite($file, "rebuild? yes \r\n");
                } else {
                    fwrite($file, "rebuild? no \r\n");
                }

output is always no.

Comment: I tested it on PHPFiddle, it seems to work : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b7r8-2hpt

Comment: Could you now make it with the else tag in there and in stead of checking the value add the fwrite line. see if that works, cant get it to work myself.

Comment: I managed to get it to work; Had to add another if isset for the no radiobox

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to use fclose($file); after all your content is written. I posted the code in another answer just in case.

Comment: Great job on helping me, but i think we both missed a pretty important aspect. Whenever the radio buttons both are NOT checked, it is supposed to not write down anything at all, whenever they are both empty now it will write no.

Comment: Ok. I edited the code in my second answer, the else becomes an elseif and checks if the value of "rebuild" is no. Is this the expected behavior ? Or do you want to cancel the writing of the file if this value is not selected ? Maybe you should select a default value ?

Comment: Yes! It works now, no, this is exactly what im trying to make, as my form (whenever it is done) Has up to 100 input types wich won't be used each and everytime the form is in use, so if i keep the emtpy one's out of the file it will be a lot less messy. Thanks a lot you made me learn a lot today.

Comment: :) glad I could help !

Comment: Just one last quick question. If i am going to add more radio buttons (i will do that, but they will all be yes or no related) is it a good idea to make this into a function? and how?

Comment: Yes it's a good idea :) Let me write the code for that, I'll post the PHPFiddle link here.

Comment: Good to know I'm atleast thinking in the right way.. :p, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the code for the form, which has now PHP in it : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r62m-fg7g And this is the code for the sendinfo.php file : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k2ay-dqz2 I commented the important parts, but I think you'll see the benefits of what I added. Let me know

Comment: I don't know if i'm allowed to ask, but can you look in your google hangouts (send you an invite.) since this topic might get to large and the main problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="rebuild" value="yes"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="rebuild" value="No"><label>No</label>

and get the value using 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo    $rebuild  = $_POST['rebuild'];
    die;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one does not work. i get the following error : Notice: Undefined index: rebuild in C:\wamp\www\sendinfo.php on line 16

Comment: name="rebuild", rebuild is the name of your input box.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I tested, the file is written correctly and the value for "rebuild" is also correct :

```
<form action="sendinfo.php" method="post" id="form">
    -Title:<br>
    <input type="text" class="u-full-width" name="title" placeholder="Insert a title" >
    <br>-Date<br>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="date" placeholder="Click to add a date"><hr>
    <br>-Buildyear:<br>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="buildyear" placeholder="click to add buildyear">

    <br>-rebuild<br>
    <input id="1" type="radio" name="rebuild" value="yes"><label for="1">Yes</label>
    <input id="2" type="radio" name="rebuild" value="no"><label for="2">No</label><hr>

    <input type="submit" value="send" class="u-full-width">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
    //variables
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $buildyear = $_POST['buildyear']; 

    //in browser 
    echo "<h1>The inserted data has been locally stored as " . $title . " " . $date . ".txt</h1>";
    echo "<p>click <a href='index.html'>Here</a> to return to the previous screen</p>";

    //write text file.
    $file = fopen($title . " " . $date . ".txt","w");
    if ($date) fwrite($file, "Date: " . $date . "\r\n");
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
    if ($buildyear) fwrite($file, "Buildyear: " . $buildyear . "\r\n");
    if (isset($_POST['rebuild']) && $_POST['rebuild'] == 'yes') { 
        fwrite($file, "rebuild? yes \r\n");
    } 
    elseif (isset($_POST['rebuild']) && $_POST['rebuild'] == 'no') { 
        fwrite($file, "rebuild? no \r\n"); 
    }

    fclose($file);
?>
```